# Error in Electron and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am pretty new to electron and node.js I am following a tutorial of how to make a shopping list application but when I try to run it (use: “npm start”), it says this:

```
App threw an error during load C:\Users\user\Documents\JavaScript\Electron\Shopping List\main.js:56
            },
            ^   SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:606:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Users\user\Documents\JavaScript\Electron\Shopping List\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:287:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\JavaScript\Electron\Shopping List\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:328:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\JavaScript\Electron\Shopping List\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:365:3)
```

This is my code:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const {app , BrowserWindow , Menu} = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;

//Listen for the app to be ready
app.on("ready" , function(){
    //Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    //Load HTML file into the main window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname , "mainWindow.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes:true
    }));

    //Build menu from template
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);

    //Insert the menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

//Handle CreateAddWindow function
function CreateAddWindow()
{
   //Create new window
    addWindow = new BrowserWindow
    ({
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        title: "Add to shopping list"
    });
    //Load HTML file into the main window
    addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname , "addWindow.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes:true
    })); 
}


const mainMenuTemplate = 
[
    {
        label:"File",
        submenu:
        [
            {
                label:"Add Item",
                CreateAddWindow()
            },
            {
                label: "Clear Items"
            },
            {
                label:"Quit",
                accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+Q" : "Ctrl+Q",
                click()
                {
                    app.quit();
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I am sorry that I used hestabin, when I tried to paste the code it made problems.

Comment: There's something wrong with `{ label: "Add Item", createAddWindow() }`. Object properties must have keys and values.

Comment: Line 56 : `{
                label:"Add Item",
                CreateAddWindow()
            }` This is not a valid object. You're missing a key

Comment: @Li357 oops sorry, I basically repeated what you said